# How to make a separate branch when in detached head state?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-detached-head

I took over a project in a `detached HEAD` state. I don't know for how many commits it's been in that state. I'm currently on `main` and want to create a new branch `feature1`. When I create this branch and then check back to `main`, most of the recent work is gone. The `feature1` branch is the only place that all the recent work exists. How should I handle this so that I can have `main` up to date, and `feature1` up to date?

Comment: There's a lot of strange wording here. I think once you realize that a branch is simply a pointer to a commit, and that you can change what commit a branch points to, then you would word this question differently, and perhaps the question might even answer itself. Also, when you say you want `main` and `feature1` to be up to date, do you mean you want them to point to the same commit? I'm guessing you just need to merge the commit ID with the "recent work" into `main`. (Or, if you already made a branch called `feature1` pointing to that commit, you could also merge `feature1` into `main`.)

Comment: Also, your title question asks how to create `feature1` from the detached commit, but your explanation makes it sound like you did it already. Which btw, to point `feature1` to the commit-id you like, can be done like this: `git branch feature1 <desired-commit-id>`